# Fractional scaling on ubuntu 19.04 doesn't seem to work well

Tags: 19.04

I installed ubuntu 19.04 recently mainly because I was interested in the fractional scaling (even if experimental).

I am connecting my laptop to a 1080p tv, the 100% scale is just not big enough and everything looks low res (mainly the text) so I decided to try the fractional scaling. But weirdly the 125% becomes too big and buggy. Actually there is no difference between 125%, 150%, 175% and 200% in my case.

Has anyone used the fractional scaling with good results ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fractional scaling is an experimental feature that works only when you are using the Wayland display server. If you performed a standard install of Ubuntu 19.04, you are using Xorg, the legacy display server. This is why fractional scaling does not work.